# The force between two magnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

Does anyone know how to find the attraction/repulsion force between two magnets with arbitrary shapes. 
What is the general formula for this ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The classic equation is:

$$F = B^2 \cdot A$$

You need to find out the area of your magnet face for $A$.

The $B$ is generally difficult. You will need a flux meter for an accurate idea.

Comment: Thank you, The B, is the magnetic field one magnet and A is the surface of the other ?

Comment: yes B is the magnetic flux / field... A is the surface area of your magnet